# render a component after some time with setTimeout ( ReactJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I want to render one component inside my App.Js after some time pass with setTimeout, there is any way to do that?

when I try, nothing happens...

my code:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <GlobalStyle />

      <SearchProvider>
        <Header />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            {setTimeout(() => {
              return;
              <>
                <InitialLoad />
                <Home />
              </>;
            }, 1200)}
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/series">
            <Series />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/movies">
            <MoviesPage />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/popular">
            <PopularPage />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/resultado-de-busca">
            <SearchPage />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </SearchProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

want my InitialLoad and Home Components show after 1200 time, but nothing happens, how I fix it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that in the Route:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {

const [isDisplayed, setIsDisplayed] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    setIsDisplayed(true);
  }, 1200);
}, []);

return (
    <Router>
      <GlobalStyle />

      <SearchProvider>
        <Header />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            {isDisplayed &&
              <>
                <InitialLoad />
                <Home />
              </>;
            }
         </Route>
      //the rest of your component
```

Comment: Make sure to clear the interval as well to prevent error. For example, `let interval = setInterval(() => setIsDisplayed(true), 1200))` followed by returning a callback function `() => clearInterval(interval)` as this will act as the `componentWillUnmount`

Answer (score 3):

Route is to choose what component to render depends on your path (URL).
if you want to refresh your component, you need to change state value, or props value from parent.

try something like this:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isHide, setIsHide] = useState(true);

  setTimeout(() => setIsHide(false), 5000);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>testing delay render</h1>
      {!isHide ? <div>show after 5 seconds</div> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would probably be to use hooks in React. Essentially creating your components`<InitialLoad /> <Home />` as usual in App.js but set display:none at the start, and then have your setTimeout() change the state and display your components.

This article may help
https://reactgo.com/settimeout-in-react-hooks/